# Delete especific lines numbers with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a script that delete especifics lines of a `.txt` file by it number. I alreay got it:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1delims=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
echo %%a >>newfile.txt
) >nul
```

It works fine and delete the line number '1'. But if i put more lines to delete, it doesn't work, see below:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1,5,8) delims=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
echo %%a >>newfile.txt
) >nul
```

What is worong?

Comment: `Skip` doesn't work like that, you'll need to count the lines using `Find`/`FindStr` or by iterating a variable count.

Comment: What is wrong? your spelling! ;-) Anyway, type `for /?` into a command prompt window to learn how the `/F` variant works; `skip` defines the number of lines to skip from the beginning, so `skip=3` skips lines 1, 2 and 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already noted in the comments, `skip` doesn't help. Instead add line numbers (with `find /v /n ""`) and output the original line (token2) without the line number, if the line number (token1) is not in the list:

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%a in ('type test.txt^|find /v /n ""') do (
    echo/%%a|findstr /x "1 5 8" >nul || echo/%%b
))>newfile.txt
```

(`findstr` switch `x` is important to compare the whole number, so `2018` isn't found with `findstr "1"`)

`||` works as "if previous command (`findstr`) failed, then"

Comment: Very similar to my answer, redirecting to find you can omit the type command and also drop the `---------- TEST.TXT` message. +1

Comment: @LotPings I like the pipe method more, because it's more intuitive (although I guess, redirection might be faster with big files) (Same with prefering `find` to `findstr` - just personal gust)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) are the tools to use.
I add in [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) on fail `||` or success `&&`
if findstr does **not** detect the current line number (produced by the /n option) enclosed in commas in the echoed skip variable the Line is written to newfile.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\09\SO_50777309.cmd
@echo off
:: generate test.txt with Line1..10
(for /l %%A in (1,1,10) do @Echo=Line%%A) >test.txt

Set "skip=,1,5,8,"
(for /f "tokens=1,*delims=:" %%a in (' findstr /n "^" ^<test.txt'
) do Echo=%skip%|findstr ",%%a," 2>&1>NUL ||Echo=%%b
)>newfile.txt

type newfile.txt
```

Sample output

```
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line6
Line7
Line9
Line10
```

Comment: LOL `echo %%a|findstr "<list>"` vs. `echo <list>|findstr `%%a` - `:D`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant without a pipe (`|`), which should be faster. Also lines with leading colons (`:`) or brackets (`[`/`]`) should be treated correctly here:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_FILE=test.txt"
set "_FNEW=newfile.txt"
set "_SKIP=,1,5,8,"

> "%_FNEW%" (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        for /F "delims=:" %%K in ("%%L") do (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if "!_SKIP!"=="!_SKIP:,%%K,=,!" (
                echo(!LINE:*:=!
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```